# Does cp --update work with a samba share?

Tags: samba, cp

I have the impression that files I copy to a mounted samba share with **cp -u** are copied also when in fact the source file is older than the destition file. Or are there other timestamps then the one I see in the file manager that are relevant for this option?

**mount** gives:

```
//IP/RAID6 on /home/ben/Benshare/OMV type cifs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=USERNAME,domain=,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=1000,forcegid,addr=IP,unix,posixpaths,serverino,mapposix,acl,rsize=1048576,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
```

(I changed IP and USERNAME.)

Comment: It depends on how do you mount Samba share. GVFS-mounting [does not preserve timestamps](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/336761). But `mount -t cifs` does. How do you mount Samba share?

Comment: I mount it via fstab noauto and then mount it in the file manager (PCmanFM) when I need it. So t Ihink I mount it with -t cifs since this is in the fstab but maybe the filemanager uses GVFS?

Comment: You should check the output of `mount` command after share mounting and then determine how your share was mounted :) And of course you can test `cp -p` behaviours.

Comment: I never used that. :) Thanks, I updated the question.